# Programmatically Compose Email using my mail account without configure in iphone's mail client

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email

In My Iphone Application,programmatically  i have to sent Email without end user's knowledge (even end user should not know ,program sending email and receiving).if i use  MFMailComposeViewController (MessageUI.framework), user need to config and able to see inbox.

I am new to this concept.  can you please just give some path to get solution, like which framework or library i need to use in my app for this work. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure such an app will be rejected by Apple when you submit it to the app store.  Doing things like this behind the user's back is considered off limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [this](https://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp) smtp library for iPhone

Good luck.

Comment: i have download that app and try to execute i got exception as  +[NSStream getStreamsToHostNamed:port:inputStream:outputStream:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3eba50f8
2011-01-04 11:03:26.001 SMTPSender[1974:307] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSStream getStreamsToHostNamed:port:inputStream:outputStream:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3eba50f8'

Comment: Try from http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/source/checkout I this in one project and woks fine.