# How to log in to gmail through programming

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone application in that I have to log in to gmail through my program and then from that account I have to send an email to application users automatiocally. I dont want to show the sending mail window to user. Please give some solution..........

Comment: You could try creating an e-mail and sending it via SMTP, specifying the desired account as the source address.  Then you don't have to muck with individual e-mail providers at all.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591489/programmatically-compose-email-using-my-mail-account-without-configure-in-iphone

Comment: -1. "Please give some solution" - it is better if you show what you have tried/searched for/etc, otherwise it seems like you are just asking us to do your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done through webservices but it may not be a good idea to implement it.

I think your idea wont be very successful with iPhone environment as Apple wont approve your idea.

I think you will understand this better if you go through Apple's Developer App Guidelines for iOS.

That is because while sending mail or to login into gmail you would require user's permission and you cannot send email to user without his permission.

Hope this helps you